# How do I put a value in span element within my <td>

Tags: jquery

I need to put the value from JQuery to span in the following:

```
<td>Cholesterol</td>
<td>
 <input type="text" name="txt_cholesterol" id="txt_cholesterol" class="info"/>
 <span class="result"></span>
</td>
<td>
 <span class="low">116</span>-<span class="high">254</span>
</td>
```

Jquery not working:

```
$(".info").keyup(function(){

   var a = $(this).val(); 
   var low = $(this).closest('td').next().find('.low').html(); 
   var high =$(this).closest('td').next().find('.high').html(); 

    if (a < parseInt(low))
    {



    $(this).closest('span').html('L');
    }
    if (a > parseInt(high))
    {
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('.result').html('H'); 
    }

});
```

Comment: Next will jump from the current TD to the next item after that TD (on the same level as that TD). So don't use next and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).next('span.result').html('L');
```

instead of

```
$(this).closest('span').html('L');
```

closest is used search parent element. refer this http://api.jquery.com/closest/

use the same for H

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
$(".info").keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $td = $this.parent('td').next();
    var a = $this.val();
    var low = $td.find('.low').html();
    var high = $td.find('.high').html();

    if (a < parseInt(low, 10)) {
        $this.next().html('L');
    }
    if (a > parseInt(high, 10)) {
        $td.find('.result').html('H');
    }

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".info").keyup(function(){

var a = $(this).val();
var low = $(this).parent().next().find('.low').html();
var high =$(this).parent().next().find('.high').html();

if (a < parseInt(low))
{
    $(this).siblings('.result').html('L');
}
if (a > parseInt(high))
{
    $(this).siblings('.result').html('H');
}

});
```

[See working example](http://jsfiddle.net/RXJAz/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this working script on http://jsfiddle.net/nrpCR/

```
$(".info").on('keyup', function(e) {

    var self = $(this);
    var a = self.val();
    var low = self.parent('td').next().find('.low').html();
    var high = self.parent('td').next().find('.high').html();


    console.log(a, low, high, $(self).parent());

    if (a < parseInt(low)) {



        self.next('span').html('L');
    }
    if (a > parseInt(high)) {
        self.next('span').html('H');
    }

});​
```